# Jquery validation not validate multi select box in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have two select box(dropdpwn) in my page. i validate my form using jQuery validation plugin but this plugin not validation two select box.

JS:

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        lastname: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

HTML :

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="firstname">Nome:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Insira o seu nome próprio" name="firstname" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="lastname">Apelido:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">€</span>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Insira o seu apelido" name="lastname" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="lastname">selectBox 1</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">€</span>
           <select class="required form-control">
               <option value="0"></option>
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="lastname">selectBox 2</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">€</span>
           <select class="required form-control">
               <option value="0"></option>
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

How do can fix this problem for each() selectbox.

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/hTPY7/1435

Comment: You are missing the equals sign, `=`, on all `value` attributes... `value"0"` is not correct.  The broken syntax is even highlighted in your jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You must have a unique `name` attribute on each element.  This is a requirement of the jQuery Validate plugin.

2) The first `option` must have `value=""` and not `value="0"`.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/hTPY7/1436/**

---

3)  OP's demo is broken because he keeps using the same `id` twice.  For valid HTML, every `id` **must** be unique on a page.

**DEMO with ID:  http://jsfiddle.net/hTPY7/1441/**

Comment: Sure You Right! please see my last update: i add `id="test"` to each select box. and i have this problem:`This field is required.` error not show in last select box.http://jsfiddle.net/hTPY7/1439/

Comment: @user27133, I have no idea what you're talking about.  `"This field is required"` is properly shown on _everything_ in [my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hTPY7/1436/)!

Comment: your demo not complete! see this demo : jsfiddle.net/hTPY7/1439

Comment: @user27133, Your demo is broken because you've duplicated the same `id`.  `id` **must** be unique.  In this case, you don't even need `id`... see my original demo.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to add the name attribut to both select boxes **and set the first option to no text and no value**

```
<select name="s1" class="required form-control">
              ^--  Don't forget to add different names for both select
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

<kbd>**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTPY7/1437/)**</kbd>

Comment: And nobody noticed the missing `=` in here:  `value"0"`

Comment: @Khalid: add missing `=` and `id` to select box. your code so not worked. http://jsfiddle.net/hTPY7/1435/

Comment: @Khalid:  jsfiddle.net/hTPY7/1430 not work. you see :`This field is required.` error in last select box?

Comment: @user27133  Check this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hTPY7/1437/ and check my post to see the update

Comment: @Khalid: in last select box you not add `id="test1"` and `This field is required.` error not show in last select box.http://jsfiddle.net/hTPY7/1439/

Comment: @user27133 when you use the id the message is shown to="id" , however id you remove the id it depends on the name="s1" , no what I suggest to you is to use the selector `" select[name=s1] or select[name=s2] "` for css or for jQuery `$("select[name=s1]")`

Comment: The OP can use an `id` if he wants... he just can't use the same `id` twice.  In other words, the `id` has nothing to do with how this plugin works but if you have invalid HTML, like a duplicate `id`, you will break the JavaScript.